# Custom field value set to permalink only on new post, But they change it every time it's updated

Tags: wordpress

I want to set the permalink slug using the custom field value for the first save only, but it is not working.

The code below changes the slug not only for the first save, but also for every update.

```
function custom_slug_auto_setting( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {

  return $_POST['custom_field_title'];
 
}
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'custom_slug_auto_setting', 10, 6 );
```

For the second and subsequent saves, I want to keep the slug set for the first save.

I tried using the filter hook for `wp_insert_post` to specify post_name only for the first save, but that didn't work well either.

Is there any good solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save_post` or `save_post_{$post->post_type}` Fires once a post has been saved. The dynamic portion of the hook name, `{$post->post_type}`, refers to the post type slug.

We need to discard any updates autosave or revision actions. The WordPress autosave system fire every 60 seconds.

- @See https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/

The `$update` parameter is supposed to determined whether this is an existing post being updated. It applies more specifically to a post autosave revision. The `$update` parameter will always be true when firing through `wp_publish_post`. But that isn't true for its usage in `wp_insert_post` (See the following wordpress stackexchange answer and comments for more details...).

- @See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185991/190376

In our case, the `wp_publish_post` function publish a post by transitioning the post status.

- @See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_publish_post/

By additionally crosschecking the post status we can effectively determine whether it is indeed a non-existing post.

If you are calling a function such as `wp_update_post` that includes the `save_post` hook, your hooked function will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function before calling the function you need, then re-hook it afterward.

- @See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/#avoiding-infinite-loops

`save_post` will fire on post Update (eg: Autosave) or Publish which is why we're runing into an infinite loop.

@See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19539/190376

```
<?php

add_action( 'save_post', 'wpso74121743', 10, 3 ); //can be replaced by save_post_{$post->post_type}

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpso74121743' ) ) {

    function wpso74121743( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

        if ( ! wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) && ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && ! $update && $post->post_status == 'auto-draft' ) {

            $override_post_name = sanitize_title( get_post_custom_values( 'custom_field_title', $post_id ), get_the_title( $post_id ) );

            add_action( 'save_post', 'wpso74121743', 10, 3 ); //can be replaced by save_post_{$post->post_type}

        
            wp_update_post( array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_name' => $self,
            ) );
        
            add_action( 'save_post', 'wpso74121743', 10, 3 ); //can be replaced by save_post_{$post->post_type}


        };

    };

};
```

Comment: Your code worked. Thank you.

However, every time I update it, the slug changes.
Sorry for my lack of explanation.

The behavior I am looking for is
1. only the first save sets the value of the custom field to the slug
2. allow the slug to be changed in the sidebar of the editor.

General post should also have the above specifications. (except that the custom field value is set to the title)

Comment: I tried using the new `wp_insert_post_data` filter hook and setting the custom field value to `post_title` in `$data` to see if that would cause the same slug handling as general post, but it did not work.

Comment: It achieved the behavior I was looking for. Thank you for your help.